# MarginLayoutParams ClassCastException on a ListView with SwipeRefresh

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm implementing pull to refresh gesture on a ListView and I have this simple layout xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer_lgpin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
            android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
            android:dividerHeight="5dp"
            android:divider="@color/grey"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Since I use SwipeRefreshLayout it's giving  a ClassCastException

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams
```

on this non related code that I use for other purposes

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)listview.getLayoutParams();
mlp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 300);
```

If I remove the SwipeRefreshLayout it works fine. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SwipeRefreshLayout` is not using a custom `LayoutParams` that extend `MarginLayoutParams` for it's children. It's is just using `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`. That's why it doesn't have any result if you set a margin for `SwipeRefreshLayout's` child in xml.

That's why you cannot cast a result of `getLayoutParams()` to `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams`.

Comment: And theres any alternative for doing that? (put a down margin on the listview child)

Comment: Depending on your exact needs you can: 1. Set a `bottomPadding` on `SwipeRefreshLayout` or 2. Set a `bottomPadding` on `ListView` and `clipToPadding` set to false

Comment: I put a footerview on the listview dinamically because I must remove it sometimes programatically. Thanks!